# Enqueue method of PriorityQueue not working

Tags: c++

I am having trouble implementing a Priority Queue. Whenever I execute the following code, the first item in the text file prints, but the program stalls after that.

```
void loadCustomerData(){
    double simClock, avgSelectionTime;
    int items;

    ifstream myfile ("arrival.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open()){
      while ( myfile >> simClock >> items >> avgSelectionTime){

        Customer cust(simClock, items, avgSelectionTime) ;
        cout << cust << endl;
        Event e(EventType::Arrival, simClock, cust);
        events.enqueue(e);
      }
      myfile.close();
    }else
    throw(1);
}
```

If I comment out the line that enqueues in PriorityQueue "events", they will all print. So I am thinking that there is a problem in the enqueue method. I am guessing it has to do with the way my nodes are set up, because it was throwing compiling errors before. If anyone could tell me where I have gone wrong, that would be much appreciated. Here is the code for my priority queue:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T> class MyPriorityQueue
{
  private:
    struct Node{
      Node * next;
      double priority;
      T value;
      Node(T value, double priority, Node * next = NULL){
        this->next = next;
        this->value = value;
        this->priority = priority;
      }
    };
    Node *head;
  public:
    int size = 0;

    MyPriorityQueue(){
      head = NULL;
      size = 0;
    }
    ~MyPriorityQueue(){
      if(head){
        Node * lead = head->next;
        Node * follow = head;
        while(lead){
          delete(follow);
          follow = lead;
          lead = lead->next;
        }
        delete(follow);
      }
    }
    void enqueue(T item){
      Node *temp, *q;
      temp->priority = item.simTime;
      temp->value = item;
      if (head == NULL || temp->priority < head->priority){
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
        size ++;
      }
      else{
        q = head;
        while (q->next != NULL && q->next->priority <= temp->priority){
          q=q->next;
          temp->next = q->next;
          q->next = temp;
          size ++;
        }
      }
    }
    Event dequeue(){
      Node *temp;
      temp = head;
      head = head->next;
      return temp->value;
      free(temp);
      size --;
    }
};
```

Comment: `Node *temp; temp->priority = ...` That's undefined behavior--you're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer. Looks like you're missing a call to `new` (and in fact you never once dynamically allocate memory ANYWHERE. What do you think you're freeing in dequeue? (you should be using `delete` instead of `free`))

Comment: @scohe001 So I had a line after Node *temp like "temp = new Node();" but then I got compilation errors which say that I do not have enough parameters. But then when I add an unparameterized constructor in the Node struct, I get even more compilation errors. Should I have left that in?

Comment: That's no surprise, `Node` doesn't have a constructor that takes no arguments (we call that a "*default constructor*") and since you made a constructor, a default constructor isn't made automatically for you. Try `Node *temp = new Node(item, item.simTime);`. However, this is only the first of many problems here...